# DAX returning incorrect total in total row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have four input columns "Location, Material, Revenue, Volume". I need to create a new column "STG_Measure" using DAX. This expression is returning wrong value for total row. "STG" column has expected output.

```
STG_Measure = IF(
                    COUNTROWS(VALUES(Sheet1))=1
                    ,DIVIDE([YTD_Revenue],[YTD_Volume])
                    ,SUMX(
                            VALUES(Sheet1[Material])
                            ,DIVIDE([YTD_Revenue],[YTD_Volume])
                        )
            )
```

I tried placing other columns in SUMX function but it didn't work. In actual data Revenue and Volume are also measures returning YTD totals.

[image: Power BI Table Visual]

Comment: This is not possible to answer without full information about your setup.
What is the definition of [YTD_Revenue] and [YTD_Volume]?
I have tried setting up the exact scenario that you have on your screenshot, and I've replaced the [YTD_Revenue] and [YTD_Volume] with a simple SUM([Revenue]) and SUM([Volume]). Using this definition, I get the expected results.

Comment: @RasmusDybkjær Thank you for the response. I did this on Power BI desktop. Yes, to replicate the issue even I sure SUM(Volume) and SUM(Revenue). I fixed the issue by including both Location and Material in SUMX by using SUMMARIZE function instead of VALUES function.